# Entitlement Process Deletion Issues

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone, entitlement-process

So, first things first. What I am trying to here is to Delete a version of Entitlement Process. While doing so I got a list of Cases with this:

> You can't delete this entitlement process because it's applied to one or more entitlements. Remove it from the entitlements and try again.

The interesting thing about the list of cases was that there were two types of cases:

1. Cases with Entitlement field populated with an Entitlement (Type 1).
2. Cases with Entitlement field Empty (Type 2).

Now, as we don't use the Entitlement Process now and don't want to, I went ahead and Deleted the Type 1 Cases(*Deleting because we can't update these cases (don't ask)*).

**For Type 2 Cases**, I had no Idea why these cases are even on the reference list. But, these cases did have CaseMilestone related list and some completed Milestones. As we cannot delete these CaseMilestones records, all I was left with was to delete the Entitlements. So, I did and deleted the Type 2 cases too.

But when I again tried to delete that Entitlement Processes, the Type 2 Cases list was still getting referenced, *somehow*. I removed all these cases from Recycle bin too.

I am in the dark here. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes dekha that Kya: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233517&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Yes, this requires updating the cases (which we can't).

Comment: Lets see if someone has similar experience otherwise discuss tomrw..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to explain why but if you wait ˜24h after deleting the associated cases and entitlements, you'll be able to delete the entitlement process version.